# How to compile and run QTP script from command line

Tags: testing, command-line, compilation, qtp

I want to use a text file containing the source code of the QTP script, and compile it (create the  usr,cfg,usp etc files that get created when we manually "save" a script in QTP) by using the command line. Is there a way to do both?

Comment: I want to do it because all of my scripts get committed on an SVN repository, and the script's complete file is heavy, so I want to commit only text file containing the actually code, and I need a way to compile this text file and run through cmd, so that anyone who wants to use the code can just add the name of the script and its path, and is able to compile and run the script (or just compile) and then launch QTP and be able to run this code. If there is way, I'd really appreciate your help :)

Comment: If you look up "Action Object" in QTP´s online help index, you´ll find the OTA/AOM object representing a QTP action. I.e. you can use the automation interface to create a new test and assign it the scriptcode you want. This, however, requires a QTP instance to be fired up since OTA is just a language interface into QTP. If you want to create a test with all companion files without starting QTP, you´d have to research the internal data file formats, and have to create code that creates them properly. (Using a template might work, but might miss some details that are variable.)

Comment: And for a test to function properly, it is not sufficient to save its scriptcode. There are myriads of config details and other state data that is part of a test, and you´d lose that if you just save the scriptcode and re-create the test from scratch when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

All those extra files in QTP/UFT are for when you're doing "more" than just writing a script.  It stores the test description, associated repositories, parameters, recovery scenarios, etc.  If you're writing test logic in a text file, there's a good chance you're not using any of that extra stuff either.

Take any blank QTP/UFT test to create a "template" of a valid test.  Then all you have to do is replace the 'Action1/script.mts' file with the contents of your text file.

If you want do to all of this from a command-line, you'll need to write a simple console-based application to do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: but to run that file i'd need to create a new script in QTP , paste the code and then run it, can it be done through command line? as there are hundreds of my scripts that need to be used by the testing team and all the files in the script cannot be put up in the repository for it gets heavy sized. 
Can you help me in writing the console based program? or any reference wich I can use to write the program?

Comment: So i want that if there is lets say test.vbs file, having the code, i want to be able to run some commands on cmd that will create all these extra files without having to launch QTP. Also if there is are some functions associated with the script, that too dznt have to be specifically be added by adding it as resource. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the problem, I´d make sure that run results never are saved in the test´s directory, and **apply SVN on the whole directory of a test, or to the whole "tests" subdirectory root**.

This might result in quite some subdirectory structure, but it has a meaning (for QTP), and without run results, it´s not hundreds of files, or megabytes, so SVN can indeed chew on them quite well.

Alternatively, you could use QC to save your tests in a QC repo, and enable version control in it. Then, QC will handle the "bundling" of all files of a tests, and guarantee that only one user can modify a given test.

Point is, if you just put the script into SVN, and, when you need it, re-create the other files programmatically, you lose info like (not limited to):

- data table name, tab structure, content local repository content
- associated repository file(s)
- associated library file(s) run settings
- ActiveScreen screens expected values for checkpoints
- Action properties
- Action parameters (formal and actual)
- Action call hierarchy (test flow)
- Subactions´ script content

which probably is unacceptable except for the simplest most trivial tests. **So I recommend you drop the idea of just saving the script content.**

Comment: Thank you for your detailed coment TheBlastOne :)
Ive done the scripting in a way that I dont need to use any object repository, function library association or any other kind of external file information. the application under testing has objects that change frequently, so we collaborated with the developers and found out a way to access all the objects without storing them in to the repository.

Comment: We have associated an identification property with every GUI object in the application code, thus the need to use object repository is removed. 
As far as the function library and other external file associations are concerned, I have used ExecuteFile method to access the external files, and also the path to those files is made relative by using the Environment variables "TestDir" and "TestName".
So to sum it up, I can use just my code and paste it into the newly created QTP script and it will run successfully.

Comment: So the only issue left is again, not being able to find a way to run the script using just the script/code file.